# iOS 11 navigator.getUserMedia is undefined in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, html, webrtc, mediadevices

After the iOS 11 release we managed to run a livescan qrcode scanner in Chrome (on iOS devices), we were in October 2017. We used a patched version of instascan (https://github.com/schmich/instascan). Everything was fine till... (I don't know exactly when) it stopped working.
Is it maybe related to the adoption of WKWebView? (https://blog.chromium.org/2016/01/a-faster-more-stable-chrome-on-ios.html)
After simple tests we have realized that navigator.getUserMedia or  navigator.mediaDevices is undefined now.

Is there an alternative way to make it working again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chrome on iOS is based on a webkit webview and that does not support getUserMedia. See this chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458

I doubt it ever worked.